# NSURLConnection queue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using a NSURLConnection to send data relative to one operation for a web service. Now the user will be able to work offline and I will need to implement a synchronise button that will send data relative to n operations, and I'm not sure how to deal with a queue of NSURLConnection consistently.

Any thoughs?

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with accepting user submissions offline and setting up a queue with NSUserdefaults.  If user is online, the entry will hit the web service for a single type submission and database entry.

If offline I store the user's data object into NSUserDefaults and set a flag that I have content that needs to be uploaded.

When reachability changes, if I have data to be uploaded I send the content to a slightly different service that I've setup to receive batched data.  The only difference is I've setup the batched service that accepts a serialized group of objects, and then deserialize on the server side and do however many database submissions.

EDIT:  I've created a sample project that currently does not connect to any webservice however I'm using tonymillion's [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) classes to test online connectivity and am setting up a queue of if the button is pushed when there is no connectivity.  The project logs the timestamp out to the console (if there is a valid connection).  If no connection exists I'm storing the timestamp to an array, when connectivity returns I iterate through the timestamps and log the stored timestamps in the array.
https://github.com/propstm/webserviceQueueSample

Comment: I think that is the best alternative, but I think I can't modify the web service. =/

Comment: How about taking your objects and after you've regained your Internet connection just doing multiple single submissions to the web service?  Maybe use GCD and make the submissions asynchronous?

Comment: Yeh, I have no idea how to implement but I will take a look. Thank you!